# To take the backup of required files of SVN repository

Tags: svn, backup, directory

I need to take the backup of one folder of my SVN repository. For this I have tried with svndump and svndumpfilter commands but of no use.

Can any one please explain how to do this with an example.

#### Update:

I have a repository in that I have one folder say "Test". Apart from this "test" there are some more folders/projects in my repository. If I want to take the full backup of my repository its consuming more memory (30 gb) so I want to shift only the "Test" folder with the history to another repository so that I can take the regular backups of only the "Test" folder (new repository) as it will take less memory. (I don't need to take the regular backups of other folders except "Test")

How can I do this?

Comment: You need the history I assume?

Comment: It is technically possible to have a dump of a part of the repository with `svndumpfilter`, and to use that separately but that would be _very_ odd. You would keep the history but everything new on that part will not have the ability to go back to the original repository. Please confirm what you exactly want to do with that backup and I'd happily give an example, but Dav's answer is most probably what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

If what you're wanting is a backup of the *current state* of the files themselves (and don't actually want the full version *history*), use [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) instead.

If you *are* trying to back up the history, then I concur with Rohith's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since SVN versions the whole tree every time a commit is made, you're likely to run into trouble if you try to backup only a portion of the source tree and then try to restore that backup.

Comment: I concur this is a bad idea, Revision numbers like you say are done accross the tree and for this reason its a bad idea to only backup certain portions as restoration would almost certainly not work without manual intervention/editing.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your followup, what you're wanting to do is to generate two new repositories from the single origin repo.

The SVN red book explains this well:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering

In a nutshell, you start with an *origin* repo and create a dumpfile, and then use **svndumpfilter** to generate the two filtered dumpfiles (one with Test, one without).

```
svnadmin dump origin > origin.dump
svndumpfilter include Test < origin.dump > testonly.dump
svndumpfilter exclude Test < origin.dump > no-test.dump
```

If you're feeling frisky, you can edit the two filtered dumpfiles to exclude the root node creations statements (talked about in the docs link).

Create the new repos:

```
svnadmin create testrepo
svnadmin create neworigin
```

Now, load the dumpfiles:

```
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid testrepo < testonly.dump
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid neworigin < no-test.dump
```

Now, you have the two new repos, so you suspend development in the *origin* repo and move to using the *neworigin* and *testrepo* repos.  From there, you can use svnadmin dump to generate the dumpfiles for just the *testrepo* and put the dumpfile in your normal backup procedure.

```
svnadmin dump testrepo > testrepo-backup.dump
```

Comment: Dear Seth,
yes i have done the same with my respository. when i use the svndumpfilter its doing something but in the last its not creating any filtered dump file !!. Anyway i will try this again let you know

Thank you very much
Mohan